# Tcl: can catch { exec } know whether a final newline was output?

Tags: tcl, exec, newline, clipboard

Consider the following:

```
% catch { exec echo "test" } result
0
% catch { exec echo -n "test" } resultnonl
0
% if { $result == $resultnonl } { echo "true" }
true
```

**Question:** Is there a way for the two resulting variables to be different?

*Use case:* I'm retrieving the contents of the clipboard and cannot differentiate between these two cases.  In Emacs, it is very common for me to kill (cut) a line without its final newline, and also very common to kill a whole line.  The clipboard only differs by the newline.

Comment: Tcl/Tk has commands to get the clipboard contents. You don't need to exec an external program for that.

Comment: @SchelteBron: Appreciated, thanks!  I'm super unfamiliar with Tcl/Tk, and was just trying to fix this script: https://github.com/apenwarr/xclipsync/blob/master/xclipfrom .

Comment: You would create a (hidden) toplevel on the "other display": `wm withdraw [toplevel .spy -screen $otherDisplay]`. Then `selection get -displayof .spy -selection CLIPBOARD`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [`-keepnewline`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/exec.html#M6) flag to `exec`. Watch:

```
catch { exec -keepnewline -- echo "test" } result
string length $result
```

Comment: Splendid, very appreciated!